# Django how to use template tag - Imagekit app

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-imagekit

**models.py**

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploads/%s/%s/profile_photo/%s" % (instance.user.username[:1], instance.user.username, filename)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ###.....
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name, 
                              blank = True, null = True,
                              height_field = 'photo_height',
                              width_field = 'photo_width')
```

So if the the current user.username is **John** the profile picture would go to **uploads/J/John/profile_photo/filename**

**views.py**:

```
from .image_processors import register_generator

#.....

@login_required
def EditProfile(request):

    register_generator()
    #....
```

**image_processors.py**

```
from imagekit import ImageSpec, register
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Thumbnail(ImageSpec):
    processors = [ResizeToFill(60, 80)]

def register_generator():
    register.generator('user_profile:thumbnail', Thumbnail)
```

Finally, the **template** contains:

```
{% generateimage 'user_profile:thumbnail' source=source_image %}
```

**My question is:**

what should source_image be? it is not specified in the official documentation.
I tried to do **source = '/static/uploads/J/John/profile_photo/EU.jpg'** , but then I get the error **'SafeText' object has no attribute 'name'**

if source_image should be the path to the image, how to dinamically specify it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source_image` needs to be a file object. (For example, `a_user_profile.photo`.)

It may not be super clear but it is in [the docs](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#generateimage):

> Additional keyword-style arguments are passed to the registered generator class. As we saw above, image spec constructors expect a source keyword argument, so that’s what we need to pass to use our thumbnail spec

And [earlier](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#defining-specs-outside-of-models):

```
source_file = open('/path/to/myimage.jpg')
image_generator = Thumbnail(source=source_file)
result = image_generator.generate()
```

If you can think of some wording that'll make this more clear, please submit a pull request!

Comment: lol, I was blind. I was reading the docs several times and always skipping these lines.

Comment: np (: I'm going to update the "earlier" example to use the same variable name (`source_file`) so the connection is a little stronger. I think they all used to be `source_image` but I changed it to make it clear it was a File-like object and not a PIL image but missed that one.